# Selenium with actions, input and webdriver: inconsistency or (likely) my own stupidity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to actually understand how to use the Selenium node driver.

Since there is virtually no documentation on the javascript/node side of the story, I am self-documenting things and making node from the code.
I am stuck at actions. In the [actions.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js) file I see for example

```
 dragAndDrop(element, location) {
    return this.mouseDown(element).mouseMove(location).mouseUp();
  }
```

And:

```
 click(opt_elementOrButton, opt_button) {
    return this.scheduleMouseAction_('click',
        command.Name.LEGACY_ACTION_CLICK, opt_elementOrButton, opt_button);
  }
```

From [this blog](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver) I saw how to use actions.
What I don't quite get, is the API. The actions.js file has methods like `mouseUp`, `mouseDown`, `mouseMove`, `click`, `keyUp`, `keyDown`, `sendKeys` .

SOME of them, I found in [input.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js), like `keyUp`, `keyDown` (under "keyboard"); confusingly, the pointer ones in input.js have different names (`press`, `release`, `move`...).

THEN SOME of them I find in [webdriver.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js) like (`click`, `sendKeys`, etc.)

Can somebody please explain:

- The relationship between the three files
- Why the inconsistency in naming  and parameter (e.g. `mouseMove(location, opt_offset)` in actions.js  vs `move({x = 0, y = 0, duration = 100, origin = Origin.VIEWPORT})` in input.js
- How to do things like `dragAndDrop()` *without* using an action

Thanks in advance, and sorry about the noise. 1 hour on this, and I just don't get it...

Comment: The javascript client is well documented: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html .

Comment: Sorry but my questions stand